# Android Retrofit JSON POST code=400, message=Bad Request

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am new to Adroid developing. I have a login form which I have to post to server. I am using Retrofit 2 library. I get response  code=400, message=Bad Request. What am i doing wrong?
Here is my interface:

```
public interface LoginService {
@POST("login")
Call<Login> createLogin(@Body Login login);
```

}

My Activity:

```
Login login = new Login(email, password);
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        LoginService loginClient = retrofit.create(LoginService.class);

        Call<Login> call = loginClient.createLogin(login);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {
                Log.d("response",response.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,":(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

And my Login class:

```
public class Login {
private String email;
private String password;

public Login(String email, String password){
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}
```

For login, app has to send json comprised like

```
{"email" : "x@y.z","password" : "abc",}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you solved this?